# How to get return value of php function into my jquery script

Tags: php, jquery

I a writing a pic upload script.  The script moves the picture to a directory and also puts it into a database.  I want to return the directory of this script to my Jquery function, and So I can then add it to a `<iframe>` or whatever.  I hope that I am running the script, but I am not sure if that is indeed occurring.  To make sure, how do I get the return value of a php function which is called by an `$(jquery).Ajax()` call?

Comment: $.ajax() will pass to your callback all the server-side script outputs. (In PHP, using echo, <?= ?>…)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using google next time and also reading official manuals..

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

good luck!

---

this is what you are looking for.

```
$.ajax({
 success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just echo the path in the php script and it will show up in the data argument of the ajax callback.